# Hibernate doesn't work after a kernel upgrade in Ubintu 20.04

Tags: kernel, hibernate

Hibernation stopped working when I updated to kernel 5.8.0-41, but it is working on kernel 5.8.0-29.

Here is my syslog on kernel 5.8.0-41

```
Feb 11 15:18:44 carbo-pc systemd[1]: Starting Hibernate...
Feb 11 15:18:44 carbo-pc kernel: [   88.990922] PM: Image not found (code -22)
Feb 11 15:18:44 carbo-pc kernel: [   89.045594] PM: hibernation: hibernation entry
Feb 11 15:18:44 carbo-pc systemd-sleep[3532]: Suspending system...
```

Why it says Image not found, it worked fine on kernel 5.8.0-29

Here is my syslog on kernel 5.8.0-29

```
Feb 11 15:12:49 carbo-pc systemd[1]: Starting Hibernate...
Feb 11 15:12:49 carbo-pc systemd-sleep[3640]: Suspending system...
Feb 11 15:12:49 carbo-pc kernel: [  361.135459] PM: hibernation: hibernation entry
Feb 11 15:13:32 carbo-pc kernel: [  361.150677] Filesystems sync: 0.014 seconds
Feb 11 15:13:32 carbo-pc kernel: [  361.150679] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
```

Please help me, I need my laptop on the go, and hibernation is very useful.
Thanks in advance.

my grub file

```
 If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-29-generic"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash mem_sleep_default=deep resume=UUID=1de75adf-4505-4beb-a421-d720f3c0d52d resume_offset=12320768"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

# uncomment to keep grub from finding other oses
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please add the output of commands `cat /etc/default/grub` and `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`

Comment: I added my grub file, for now I set my efault kernal to 5.8.0-29 to get things going...,
for initfamfs I have 3 kernels for now , 5.8.0-29, 5.8.0-41, 5.8.0-43, should I send you the verbose output?

Comment: Ok, try running `sudo update-initramfs  -u -k all` anyway. It should show `initramfs will attempt to resume from <partition>` if everything is configured correctly. Maybe running `sudo update-grub` might fix the kernel command line.

Comment: I did, no effects

Comment: I think update-initramfs for new kernels doesn't care about resume in ```/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume```, any solutions to this?

Comment: I found out that `image not found` error means it couldn't find the swap partition/file. Check if you have your swap space active.

Comment: swap is showing in ```cat /proc/swaps ``` and is active

Answer (score 0):

Updating my BIOS firmware worked for me!